# Reach a hashtable in perl

Tags: perl, hashtable

I have to match two hashtable, but its keys does not match. So i reach each hashtable and match by values. So following code does not works:

```
sub _findHashElt
{
    my ($this, $hashTarget) = @_;

    my $isFound = 0;
    my $isItemFound = 1;
    my $isHashFound = 0;
    my $result = undef;
    my %hashTable=%{$this->{templates}};
    my %hashTargetHash=%{$hashTarget};
    my %hashSubTable = undef;

    while (    (my ($key, $value) =  each(%hashTable)) 
           and ($isFound          == 0               ))
    {
        $isItemFound = 1;
        $isHashFound = 0;

        ####################################
        # DOES NOT WORK
        %hashSubTable = %{$hashTable{$key}};
        ####################################

        while (    (my ($subKey, $subValue) =  each(%hashTargetHash))
               and ($isItemFound            == 1                    ))
        {
            $isItemFound = 0;
            while (    (my ($subTableKey, $subtableValue) =  each(%hashSubTable)) 
                   and ($isItemFound                      == 0                    ))
            {
                $isHashFound = 1;
                $isItemFound = ($subValue eq $subtableValue) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }

        if ($isItemFound == 1 && $isHashFound == 1) {
            $isFound = 1;
            $result = $key;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And following code works:

```
sub _findHashElt
{
    my ($this, $hashTarget) = @_;

    my $isFound = 0;
    my $isItemFound = 1;
    my $isHashFound = 0;
    my $result = undef;

    my %hashTable=%{$this->{templates}};
    my %hashTargetHash=%{$hashTarget};
    my %hashSubTable = undef;

    while (    (my ($key, $value) =  each(%hashTable)) 
           and ($isFound          == 0               ))
    {
        $isItemFound = 1;
        $isHashFound = 0;

        while (    (my ($subKey, $subValue) =  each(%hashTargetHash))
               and ($isItemFound            == 1                    ))
        {
            ####################################
            # WORK
            %hashSubTable = %{$hashTable{$key}};
            ####################################

            $isItemFound = 0;

            while (    (my ($subTableKey, $subtableValue) =  each(%hashSubTable)) 
                   and ($isItemFound                      == 0                    ))
            {
                $isHashFound = 1;

                $isItemFound = ($subValue eq $subtableValue) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }

        if ($isItemFound == 1 && $isHashFound == 1) {
            $isFound = 1;
            $result = $key;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Please someone can tell me, what is the problem please ?

**EDIT**

```
#############################################
################# TEST PART #################
#############################################
my $this = {"templates" => {}};
my $example = {'key0' => {'key00' => 'test00', 'key01' => 'test01', 'key02' => '0', 'key03' => 'test03'},
               'key1' => {'key00' => 'test10', 'key01' => 'test11', 'key02' => '1', 'key03' => 'test13'},
               'key2' => {'key00' => 'test20', 'key01' => 'test21', 'key02' => '1', 'key03' => 'test23'},
               'key3' => {'key00' => 'test30', 'key01' => 'test31', 'key02' => '0', 'key03' => 'test33'}};
my $expected = {'key00' => 'test00', 'key01' => 'test01', 'key02' => '0', 'key03' => 'test03'};
$this->{templates}=$example;
_findHashElt($this, \%expected );
```

In the first case, the key has not been found, and in the second the key has been found ...

**EDIT**

First case:

```
$ perl myTest.pl
Key not found
```

Second case:

```
$ perl myTest.pl
Key found
{
   key01 : test01
   key00 : test00
   key03 : test03
   key02 : 0
}
```

**EDIT**

Another thing, i think it will be usefull

```
$ perl --version

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-cygwin-thread-multi-64int
(with 13 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: Usually it is best to boil down your problem to a minimal version.

Comment: i do not know how to boil down my problem to a minimal version. But i can add a full example, i it can help.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? Could you please provide some sample data for input and expected output?

Comment: Does not work means the key has not been found. And if i dump the hashtable, the same code works, and it can find the right key...

Comment: @binogure if you've got a version of your code that works, why do you need help?

Comment: to understand why it is not work in a case...

Comment: `my %hashSubTable = undef` is wrong, and if you had used the `warnings` pragma, a descriptive message would indicate such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer at my own question

> Extract from perlfunc(1) :
>
> There is a single iterator for  each hash, shared by all "each",
>   "keys", and "values" function  calls in the program; it can  be reset
>   by reading all the elements from the hash,  or by evaluating "keys
>   HASH" or "values HASH".

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~